# Read out Array Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist, html-select

I got this Array in my Script and i want it to be shown in a HTML Document after choosing a Option. In the end it has to be a calculated Value depending on the Key. Any suggestions can help me out A LOT.

```
<script> var count = { 10:80.00, 20:130.00, 30:60.00, 40:60.00, 50:60.00, 60:57.95, 70:56.10, 80:54.40, 90:52.75, 1000:51.25, 110:49.75, 120:48.35, 130:47.00, 140:45.65, 150:44.35, 160:43.10, 170:41.90, 180:40.70, 190:39.50, 200:38.35, 210:37.20, 220:36.10, 230:35.00, 240:33.95, 250:32.90, 260:31.85, 270:30.85, 280:00.00, 290:00.00, 300:00.00, 400:00.00, 500:00.00 
    }; </script>

<p> XXXX:
<select name="dropdown_menue_name"
      onchange="document.calc.output.value = nextMonth(i)">
                        
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="40">40</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="60">60</option>
                        <option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="80">80</option>
                        <option value="90">90</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                        <option value="110">110</option>
                        <option value="120">120</option>
                        <option value="130">130</option>
                        <option value="140">140</option>
                        <option value="150">150</option>
                        <option value="160">160</option>
                        <option value="170">170</option>
                        <option value="180">180</option>
                        <option value="190">190</option>
                        <option value="200">200</option>
                        <option value="210">210</option>
                        <option value="220">220</option>
                        <option value="230">230</option>
                        <option value="240">240</option>
                        <option value="250">250</option>
                        <option value="260">260</option>
                        <option value="270">270</option>
                        <option value="280">280</option>
                        <option value="290">290</option>
                        <option value="300">300</option>
                        <option value="400">400</option>
                        <option value="500">500</option>
</select></p>
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: For start... `count` is not an array..And can you be more clear what end output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zm5vo347/

```
var count = { 10:80.00, 20:130.00, 30:60.00, 40:60.00, 50:60.00, 60:57.95, 70:56.10, 80:54.40, 90:52.75, 100:51.25, 110:49.75, 120:48.35, 130:47.00, 140:45.65, 150:44.35, 160:43.10, 170:41.90, 180:40.70, 190:39.50, 200:38.35, 210:37.20, 220:36.10, 230:35.00, 240:33.95, 250:32.90, 260:31.85, 270:30.85, 280:37.20, 290:56.04, 300:23.20, 400:40.00, 500:43.32 
};
function nextMonth(){
var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("dropdown").value, 10);
document.getElementById("price").value = count[val];
}
```

and do some changes in html like below (added `id` to `select` tag and to execute `nextMonth` function on load)

```
<body onload='nextMonth()'>
<p> Select number of users:
<select onchange="nextMonth()" id='dropdown' name="dropdown_menue_name">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="70">70</option>
                    <option value="80">80</option>
                    <option value="90">90</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                    <option value="110">110</option>
                    <option value="120">120</option>
                    <option value="130">130</option>
                    <option value="140">140</option>
                    <option value="150">150</option>
                    <option value="160">160</option>
                    <option value="170">170</option>
                    <option value="180">180</option>
                    <option value="190">190</option>
                    <option value="200">200</option>
                    <option value="210">210</option>
                    <option value="220">220</option>
                    <option value="230">230</option>
                    <option value="240">240</option>
                    <option value="250">250</option>
                    <option value="260">260</option>
                    <option value="270">270</option>
                    <option value="280">280</option>
                    <option value="290">290</option>
                    <option value="300">300</option>
                    <option value="400">400</option>
                    <option value="500">500</option>
</select></p>
<label>Price per user and month:</label>
<input type="text" id="price"><br>
</body>
```

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot mate! You really gave me something to work with. I hope it didnt took to much of your time. I would upvote your post, but my reputation is not high enaugh :(

Comment: Can i ask you something? Could you please explain what are you doing in the line:  `var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("dropdown").value, 10);`  especially why it has to be a "10" after the .value   ...i dont get this.

And is ist still possible to get a "." or a " " when the Number in the Input-field gets bigger than 999? I mean something like 1.000 instead of just a 1000. Or something like 20.000,00$ would be really awesome.

Sorry I'm a bit nooby when it gets to JavaScript ^^

Comment: Very well... `document.getElementById("dropdown").value` -->this is to get what value is selected from drop down list. Say suppose, `230`..Now the whole statement reduced to something like this... `parseInt(230, 10);`. `parseInt` is a function which parses string arguments and returns `integer` value. `10` is passed as an radix argument, which means to decimal. So finally `val` variable has value 230.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can i follow you or something in StackOverflow? I would really enjoy learning from you.